# Shock absorber has dropped down

Tags: suspension, shock-absorber

I'm not sure about the proper nomenclature but it looks like my rear shock absorber (or a part of it?) has dropped and is stuck at that down position.

[image]

Car details: 2000 BMW 320d (first version of the E46 generation)

Is there a proper name for this phenomenon?
Is there a fix? Or should I just get a new one?
Is it safe to drive in the meantime?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the year/make/model of the car in question?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦ Sorry, I've now updated the question with those details.

Comment: Haha ... I've done a lot of work on my son's E46 (2001 330Ci) ... I've grown to hate that car, lol :o)

Comment: How does the other side look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the dust cover has just dropped down, which isn’t really a problem as far as the operation of the shock absorber is concerned.  The shock absorbers are obviously getting old, so it could be a sign to plan replacing them.

This screen shot taken from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFxjz_w4-v4) shows that the dust cover should be attached to the rubber buffer at the top -
[image]
The video is titled - “How to change rear shock absorber on BMW E46 Touring”